# Values aren't displaying properly after HTML is parsed to XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

My problem is this is a HTML template we use in a program. Once this template is saved it parses to XML, and where my values are supposed to be it comes out in weird places and wont capture the value where it should to use the `javascript` function. It should carry over any inputted numbers each time you generate the template on a patient. Attaching a screenshot of what it looks like after its parsed.

[image: Parsed]

```
<TD width="20%">Number of Visits</TD>
<TD><INPUT onblur=setCurrentCount(); id=currentvisit title="" style="WIDTH: 100px; MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=currentvisit min="1" max="100" ex_ctrlid="currentvisit" ex_ctrltype="Number">&nbsp;of&nbsp; 
        
<INPUT id=totalvisits title="" style="WIDTH: 100px; MARGIN: auto" accessKey="" name=totalvisits min="1" max="100" ex_ctrlid="totalvisits" ex_ctrltype="Number">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        
<INPUT id=previousvisit title="" style="MARGIN: auto" type=hidden name=previousvisit ex_ctrlid="previousvisit" ex_ctrltype="Number"></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></TD>`<TD 


<SCRIPT>

function getElementValue(id) {var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el === null)
    return null;
        
    if (el.nodeName !== "INPUT")
    return el.innerHTML;
    return el.value;

}

function setCurrentCount() {
        
// GET THE VALUES OF THE THREE TEXT BOXES
//var vTotalVisits = parseFloat(getElementValue("totalvisits")) || 0;
var vPreviousVisit = parseFloat(getElementValue("previousvisit")) || 0;
        
// IF THIS IS THE 1ST VISIT, PREVIOUS DOES NOT EXIST, SET TO ZERO
//var vCurrentVisit = document.getElementById(vCurrentVisit)
//if (vCurrentVisit) {value == vCurrentVisit.value}
//vPreviousVisit = 0;
// IF THEY SET THE CURRENT VISIT TO SOMETHING OTHER THAN 1, SET PREVIOUS TO CURRENT - 1
vPreviousVisit += 1;
//if (vPreviousVisit > 1) {
document.getElementById("previousvisit").value = vPreviousVisit;
//}
        
// SET THE CURRENT VALUE ON THE FORM
document.getElementById("currentvisit").value = vPreviousVisit;
        
// CALL THE FUNCTION WHEN THE PAGE LOADS
//if (typeof setCurrentCount == 'function') {
//setCurrentCount();
//}     
}
        
(function () {
    setCurrentCount();
 })();
        
        
        
                                    
        
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Hi. Where is the Screenshot? And removing the extreme indentation in your code would be nice.

Comment: I'm trying to edit it now sorry, page refreshed on me while I was trying to edit

Comment: @wuerfelfreak hope that's better

Comment: Thanks. Mostly good. I fixed the rest. You only need to approve the edit.

Comment: how do I approve the edit

Comment: @wuerfelfreak lol nevermind I figured it out its approved

Comment: @AshleyDaniel Is the problem resolved? I was wondering how your HTML parsed properly as XML without closing the ```INPUT``` tags!

Comment: @SreeKumar actually yes I just closed my input tags, so part of my issue is resolved. Now I just have to get the function correctly written so it will add up current visits.